# how to logrorate log hourly in linux

Tags: linux, logging

I have set the logrorate conf as follow

```
 /var/adm/ras/cherrypy/cherrypy_access.log {
  compress
  rotate 7
  maxsize 10M
  hourly
  copytruncate  
  missingok
  notifempty
}

/var/adm/ras/cherrypy/cherrypy_error.log {
  compress
  rotate 7
  maxsize 10M
  hourly
  copytruncate  
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

but it does not logrorate hourly.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried running it with `logrotate -v` to see the verbose messages?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

form the man page of logrotate.con ( man logrotate.conf ):

```
Frequency
       hourly Log files are rotated every hour.  
Note that usually logrotate is configured to be run by cron daily.
You have to change this configuration and run logrotate hourly to be
able to really rotate logs hourly.
```

and in the crontab (ubuntu version) is:

```
$ find /etc/cron.* -iname "*logrotate*"
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

you need to move to /etc/cron.hourly:

```
mv /etc/cron.daily/logrotate /etc/cron.hourly/
```

for other linux distros, logrotate can be started from systemd

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/logrotate.timer 
[Unit]
Description=Daily rotation of log files 
Documentation=man:logrotate(8) man:logrotate.conf(5)

[Timer]
#OnCalendar=daily
OnCalendar=hourly
AccuracySec=1h
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such directive as `maxsize`. Try to remove that or change it to `size`.